# how to make images link to different pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

What i want to do is to have each of the images that i m using link to a site when i click on them.The images keep changing with the setinterval() method and the function changeimage().I have some html and some javascript code: 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="TEXT/CSS" HREF="STYLES.css">
    <title>KURIA SELIDA</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<table class="tablearxikhs">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="tdarxikhs" STYLE="font-size:150%;"><a href="selidakataxwrhsewn.html"> ΚΑΤΑΧΩΡΗΣΕΙΣ </a></td>
        <td class="tdarxikhs"><a href="kuriaselida.html"><h1>ΤΑΞΙΔΙΩΤΙΚΟ ΓΡΑΦΕΙΟ </h1></a></td>
        <td class="tdarxikhs" style="font-size:150%;"><a href="selidaepikoinwnias.html">ΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑ</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h2 style="text-align: center; ">Κορυφαίοι Προορισμοί Για το 2017-2018</h2>
<center><img id="myimages" src="kalabruta1.jpg" height="230" width="600"></center>
<br><br>
The JS part:
<br><br>

<script>
    var image = document.getElementById("myimages");
    var images = ["kalabruta1.jpg", "metewra1.jpg", "naxos11.gif", "metewra2.jpg", "kalabruta2.jpg", "naxos2.jpg"];
    var i = 0;

    function changeimage() {

        if (++i >= images.length) i = 0;
        image.src = images[i];


        images[i].onclick = imglink;

    }

    setInterval(changeimage, 3000);

    function imglink() {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.gr/';
    }
</script>
```

What i have tried in order to have the images link to a site doesnt work..Can somebody help?

Comment: Why not just wrap each image in an anchor tag?

Comment: I will google it because i'm still new to JS and i dont even know what an anchor tag is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the logic of your code, however, this is my suggestion:

This line `images[i].onclick = imglink;` is using `images[i]` and that's incorrect because you're getting String objects, instead you need to replace that line with this: `image.onclick = imglink;` in order to apply the onclick event to the image.

```
<script>
    var image = document.getElementById("myimages");
    var images = ["kalabruta1.jpg", "metewra1.jpg", "naxos11.gif", "metewra2.jpg", "kalabruta2.jpg", "naxos2.jpg"];
    var i = 0;

    function changeimage() {
        if (++i >= images.length) i = 0;
        image.src = images[i];
        image.onclick = imglink;
    }

    setInterval(changeimage, 3000);

    function imglink() {
        window.location.href = 'https://www.google.gr/';
    }
</script>
```